# Tips for new users

Tags: discussion, etiquette, formatting, new-users

#### The Zen of BSE <sub>as I see it</sub>

- BSE [isn't a forum](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/)
- The search facility (top right) works great! Use it - you'll be surprised what you find.
- Your posts can be [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/278094) by anyone. This is normal. You wont loose any rep.
- [Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/278094) should lead you to update the question with more information before we answer.
- Comments are editable for a period of 5 minutes.
- Read a comment carefully before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit.
- Keep the comments area tidy, remove comments after dealing with them, even if up voted.
- A Question with many comments prompts BSE to provide a dedicated (but public) [chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq).
- Up vote a comment that helped you.
- [Up vote](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) any Answer that helped you.
- If you get a satisfactory Answer [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/278094) it.
- When you Down vote consider leaving an explanation.
- Use screenshots, learn to crop (landscape tends to make images take up less vertical space) and keep text out of the image
- Avoid resubmitting the same Question as another new Question. We *will* close it. (promise).
- If the Question didn't get an answer there's usually a good reason (and it's not because we didn't see it).
- Any of the following actions will bump your question to the front page again:

  - edit the question with more details
  - streamline the question (Imagine you had to pay per word, how much of your Question is new information)
  - include a .blend use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for permanent storage
- To emphasize words don't use capitals, they'll get edited out anyway. (promise)
- Take time to craft the Question and its Title.
- Title your Question in a way that contains the core of your Question.
- Ask 1 main thing per Question, if that's not possible then limit yourself to one topic. We might still ask you to split the Question into multiple separate Questions and will often suggest how to split it.
- We encourage you to ask as many separate *new* Questions as you need.
- Read the [markdown formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for text and code. (markdown lets you stylize your content)
- Use correct [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/278094) for your Question. *Tags are important*

For much more information read the [Full FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/278094).

Comment: +1 for having a "beginner to SE" cheatsheet. I bet most of our new users are also new to SE entirely

Comment: I'm tempted to break it out into two groups Questions and Answers , there's things i'd like to say about answers specifically.

Comment: Here is an important tip: use questions for asking questions, and answers for posting answers. do not post your opinions and advice in a question! :-)

Comment: You need a new first (or second) item in the lisst, @zeffii: "Before asking a question, use the search facility to see if the question has been asked, and answered before".

Comment: I agree brasshat!